# Updating records based on group by order by data

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-update, sql-order-by

Theres a `note` table where every user can have multiple notes. I have a users table that has a column called `last_note` that is `null` and needs to be filled based on the last note for every user in the `notes` table.

In order to select the latest note for every user I did:

```
SELECT * FROM users
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY tm DESC
```

However, I am unable to incorporate the group by and order by clauses in to my update query for obvious reasons:

```
UPDATE users u
JOIN note n
ON u.id = n.user_id
SET u.last_note = n.note
GROUP BY n.user_id
ORDER BY n.tm DESC
```

I was wondering if someone can help me figure out how I can accomplish this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why store this at all?

Comment: @Strawberry, I agree! It's just how the system was built, I don't have the power to change it, only to add to existing architecture.

Comment: I don't understand. If you don't have the power to change it, then how come you're changing it?

Comment: @Strawberry, obviously I have the power to change the database but not the actual web application architecture that was already built, basically too much time was spent on the current system, so I can't spend time on redoing things that already work, although I would if it was upto me.

Comment: But surely it's just a question of substituting one query with another!?!! Whatever, it's your party.

Comment: Right, in many different locations, it amounts to an amount of time that I won't be able to get.

Comment: Well, for next time, this is where VIEWS can be really useful

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE users u 
INNER JOIN (SELECT n.user_id, n.note 
            FROM note n 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT n.user_id, MAX(n.noteId) noteId
                        FROM note n GROUP BY n.user_id
                       ) AS A ON n.user_id = A.user_id AND n.noteId = A.noteId
           ) n ON u.id = n.user_id 
SET u.last_note = n.note
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE users u 
INNER JOIN (SELECT n.user_id, n.note 
            FROM (SELECT n.user_id, n.note 
                  FROM note n ORDER BY n.user_id, n.noteId DESC
                 ) n 
            GROUP BY n.user_id
           ) n ON u.id = n.user_id 
SET u.last_note = n.note
```

Comment: If this works, it does so because of undocumented behaviour of MySQL (unless you include the comments section of the relevant page of the manual). In consequence, I find it a bit unsatisfactory.

Comment: Cool - but you've got more subqueries than you need!